# ImmutableJS: merge two list of objects, without duplicating them

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, immutable.js

Supposing I have the below:

```
var allFoods = Immutable.List();

var frenchFood = Immutable.List([
  {
  'type': 'french fries',
  'price': 3
  },
  {
    'type': 'petit gateau',
    'price': 40
  },
  {
    'type': 'croissant',
    'price': 20
  },
]);

var fastFood = Immutable.List([
  {
  'type': 'cheeseburger',
  'price': 5
  },
  {
  'type': 'vegan burger',
  'price': 20
  },
  {
  'type': 'french fries',
  'price': 3
  }
]);
```

I want to merge both lists, in a way that I also remove dupes (in this case, *french fries*), so the expected result would be:

```
{
'type': 'french fries', // keep the first french fries
'price': 3
},
{
  'type': 'petit gateau',
  'price': 40
},
{
  'type': 'croissant',
  'price': 20
},
  {
'type': 'cheeseburger',
'price': 5
},
{
'type': 'vegan burger',
'price': 20
}
```

What I'm trying (doesn't remove dupes):

```
allFoods = frenchFood.concat(fastFood);
allFoods = allFoods.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return allFoods.indexOf(item) === pos;
});
```

Which returns arrays merged, but still duplicated.

What am I missing?

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* Methods like `indexOf` still use reference equality to  compare elements. While the two object may have the same fields, they are still different objects. Maybe you good use the `.is` method to determine equality if you used Records instead. https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is

Comment: Perhaps you want a [`Set`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set) of `Map` instead of a `List` of plain objects.

Comment: @4castle: I don't think that would help. The objects are still distinct objects.

Comment: @FelixKling Sets measure equality by value (and not by reference) using [`Immutable.is()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is)

Comment: @4castle: I understand, but `Immutable.is({foo: 42}, {foo: 42});` is `false`. The value comparison only works for Immutable values, not native JS objects. `Immutable.is(Immutable.fromJS({foo: 42}), Immutable.fromJS({foo: 42}));` is `true` (compares `Map`s).

Comment: ok so no way to make it without transforming to Set (which is a collection of unique values)? I really need a list here.

Answer (score 3):

```
const allFoods = frenchFood.concat(fastFood.filter((item) =>
   frenchFood.indexOf(item) < 0
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `reduce`

```
var result = frenchFood.concat(fastFood).reduce( (reduction, food) =>  { 
if(reduction[food.type]) {
    return reduction;
}  else { 
    return reduction.set([food.type], food);

}  
}, new Immutable.Map()).valueSeq().toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly encourage you to not nest js objects inside immutable structures. Better to wrap those objects in an Immutable.Map() or do Immutable.fromJS(yourJsObj).

Least amount of code

```
const results = Immutable.Set(frenchFood).union(Immutable.Set(fastFood));
```

However @rooftop answer fastest

https://jsperf.com/union-vs-concat-immutable

Answer (score -1):

I found a best solution (for me) on medium, link to origin answer is dead: https://medium.com/@justintulk/merging-and-deduplicating-data-arrays-with-array-reduce-efaa4d7ef7b0

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Array 1-1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Array 1-2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Array 1-3' }
]
const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Array 2-1' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Array 2-3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Array 2-4' }
]

const mergeArrObjectsUnique = (currentArr, newArr) => {
  let obj = {}

  currentArr.forEach(item => {
    obj[item.id] = item
  })
  
  newArr.forEach(item => {
    obj[item.id] = item
  })
  
  let result = [];
  
  for(let p in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p))
    result.push(obj[p])
  }

  console.log('result: ', result)
  return result
}

mergeArrObjectsUnique(arr1, arr2)
```