# Merging two pieces of mismatching data with immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, immutability, immutable.js

I have a piece of JSON data that I use to dynamically generate a form and it looks like so:

```
{
  "form": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "First Name",
        "alt": "first_name"
      },
      {
        "name": "Last Name",
        "alt": "last_name"
      },
      {
        "name": "D.O.B.",
        "alt": "dob"
      },
      {
        "name": "Primary Address",
        "alt": "primary_address"
      },
      {
        "name": "Primary City",
        "alt": "primary_city"
      },
      {
        "name": "ZIP Code",
        "alt": "zip"
      },
      {
        "name": "Country",
        "alt": "country"
      },
      {
        "name": "First 4 Phone Digits",
        "alt": "first_phone"
      },
      {
        "name": "Phone Number",
        "alt": "phone_number"
      }
    ]
  },
  "someVal": [],
  "someVal2": "a string"
}
```

When I submit this form and there are errors, I am returned errors in the following format:

```
    [
      { 
        "alt": "primary_city",
        "errors": [ "primary_city Error Message" ] 
      },
      { 
        "alt": "zip",
        "errors": [ "zip Error Message" ] 
      },
      { 
        "alt": "first_name",
        "errors": [ "first_name Error Message" ] 
      },
      { 
        "alt": "dob",
        "errors": [ "dob Error Message" ] 
      },
      { 
        "alt": "primary_address",
        "errors": [ "primary_address Error Message" ] 
      },
      { 
        "alt": "last_name",
        "errors": [ "last_name Error Message" ] 
      }
    ]
```

My goal is to merge the two to get this format, to merge the errors where the alts match:

```
    {
      "form": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "First Name",
            "alt": "first_name",
            "errors": [ "first_name Error Message" ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Last Name",
            "alt": "last_name",
            "errors": [ "last_name Error Message" ]
          },
          {
            "name": "D.O.B.",
            "alt": "dob",
            "errors": [ "dob Error Message" ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Primary Address",
            "alt": "primary_address",
            "errors": [ "primary_address Error Message" ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Primary City",
            "alt": "primary_city",
            "errors": [ "primary_city Error Message" ]
          },
          {
            "name": "ZIP Code",
            "alt": "zip",
            "errors": [ "zip Error Message" ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Country",
            "alt": "country"
          },
          {
            "name": "First 4 Phone Digits",
            "alt": "first_phone"
          },
          {
            "name": "Phone Number",
            "alt": "phone_number"
          }
        ]
      },
      "someVal": [],
      "someVal2": "a string"
    }
```

So far I've been trying to do the following:

```
import { fromJS, Map, List } from 'immutable';

import form from './json/form.json'
import config from './json/errors.json'

let list = new List([])

list.merge(fromJS(config), fromJS(form));

console.log(list);

console.log(list.toJS())
// console.log(JSON.stringify(newList, null, 2))
```

And I only get the following output:

```
List []
[]
```

I honestly have no idea how to begin merging these and the documentation isn't of much help either.

Comment: Well, you're trying to merge an object (the first set of code) with an array (the second set of code). Seems like you actually want to merge the value of the `form.fields` property on the first set of code with the array from the second...

Comment: You'll also need to tell the code that you want to match on the `alt` property. I suggest reading the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39908169/215552) for more on that.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I tried `list.merge(fromJS(errors), fromJS(form.form.fields));` but I still get an empty array. Just saw your second comment, checking it out.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan hmm, all it does is seem to combine the two arrays instead of merging them together. Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand the concept of immutability there

```
let list = new List([])

const mergedList = list.merge(fromJS(config), fromJS(form));

console.log(list); // prints empty list
```

Immutability means, that original data is not updated (e.g mutated). In your example, it means, that original `list` object still will be empty. But `.merge()` returns you a new List that has a result of merge operation.

Then you will see that lists in Immutable are merged by index. Look at this trivial example

```
const a = new List([{a: 1}, {a: 2}]);
const b = new List([{b: 3}, {b: 4}]);

const merged = a.merge(b);

console.log(merged.toJS())
// [{a: 1, b: 3}, {a: 2, b: 4}]
```

If you want to merge it not by index, but by your specific identifier, you should transfer your records into Map, keyed by `alt` field:

```
 import form from './json/form.json'
 import config from './json/errors.json'

 const formByField = form.reduce(
   (total, field) => ({...total, [field.alt]: field}),
   {}
 );
 const configByField = config.reduce(
   (total, field) => ({...total, [field.alt]: field}),
   {}
 );

 // then you can merge two Maps together

 const result = new Map().mergeDeep(fromJS(formByField), fromJS(configByField));
```

Note, that you also to use `mergeDeep` to make it recursive for every matching key